# Xcode 4.3.2 ans SBJSON

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am developing an `iOS` application. i am using `Xcode 4.3.2` and `SBJSON`, i have imported all the JSON classes to my project and it compiles fine, but when i navigate in the project , i have a crash like this : `-[__NSCFDictionary JSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

and in my code i am doing like this : `NSString *jsonString = [dic JSONRepresentation];`
dic is a `NSDictionnary.`

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, where responseString is your response string that you have received from parser.

```
SBJSON *json = [SBJSON new];    
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary*) [json objectWithString:responseString error:nil];
```

Comment: Its available and you can download it from, https://github.com/dcgrigsby/luckynumbers/tree/master/Classes. In JSON folder there are files named SBJSON.h & SBJSON.m.

Comment: The link I have suggested, is the source code to a tutorial demonstrating how to use JSON-over-HTTP on the iPhone. And you can have SBJSON class also.

Comment: I am the author of SBJson. Please replace the use of the _ancient_ SBJSON class with either the SBJsonParser or SBJsonWriter classes.

Comment: @StigBrautaset: Thanks for your kind concern. Can you please post the link here for the said topic to help out everyone?

Comment: @iApple, sure. The main repository is here: https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

Answer (score 0):

JSONRepresentation is not part of Apple's NSDictionary class.

It's a very useful category included in the JSON Api.

=> Are you using [this JSON Api](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/blob/master/Classes/NSObject+SBJson.h) ?

=> Do you import correctly the JSON Api header file ?

=> If you have a look to the code, is the JSONRepresentation category declared as :

```
@interface NSDictionary (NSDictionary_SBJsonWriting)
/// Returns a string containing the receiver encoded in JSON.
- (NSString *)JSONRepresentation;
@end
```

with the corresponding code in the .m file ?

**EDIT :**

If you are making a static library and using JSON Api in it (or other API), you should make some changes in your library's build settings and in the calling project's ones.

- in your library build settings, check the line "other linker flags". The value should be : "-ObjC"
- in the calling project's build setting, the value of "other linker flags" should be "-all_load"

Comment: yes i have done all this, do yo have already worked  with Xcode 4.3.2  and SBJSON ?

Comment: Nope, i'm still on 4.2. Is your problem happened after migrating to 4.3 ? Was it working before ?

Comment: How are you doing to convert an NSDictionnay to JSON using SBJSON ?

Comment: I include the main file (#import "JSON.h") then I just call [dictionary JSONRepresentation]; where dictionary is just a NSDictionary.

Comment: ok i am doing the same thing but it's not working,i have found this but i don't know how to do it http://transoceanic.blogspot.fr/2011/09/xcode-include-objectivec-categories-int.html

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Is your project a static library ? Have you found the line "other linker flags" in your project's build settings ? What is its value ?

Comment: my project is not a static library, it's a normal project. there is no value in the "other linker flags"

Comment: Hum I can't easily help you. Do you have a piece of code ? Have you tried to set "other linker flags" to "-all_load" ?